# Have any Star Trek space stations performed major maneuvers?

Tags: star-trek

Have Star Trek Federation space stations ever performed major maneuvers? These could be for example a 180 rotation about an axis, move to a new location, avoid a collision, enter into an orbit, etc. (All Star Treks)

Comment: I take it you didn't watch Deep Space Nine.

Comment: @Ellesedil I'm pretty sure I saw the DS9 pilot when it originally aired, but that was almost a quarter century ago. Y2K threw my positronic brain for a loop and I've seemed to have forgotton a few things along the way. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the pilot episode of Star Trek: Deep Space Nine, they use the station's thrusters and deflector field to move DS9 from orbit around Bajor XI (AKA "Bajor", the one that the Bajorans come from) to the mouth of the Bajoran wormhole. The wormhole is located in the Denorios belt between Bajor IX and Bajor X. Based on the distances between planets in our own solar system, this relocation was somewhere between 10<sup>8</sup> and 10<sup>9</sup> miles.

Here is a map of the Bajoran system. Bajor XI is the largest planet, fourth from the left. The numbers above the planets don't seem to refer to distance, at least in any recognizable unit system, but it's clear that there's another planet orbiting between DS9 and Bajor XI, so the distance traveled is indeed in the interplanetary range.

[image: An LCARS-style computer graphic showing a system with 9 inner planets, a white ring presumably corresponding to the Denorios belt with DS9 indicated in this location, 5 outer planets, a comet, and a lot of seemingly random numbers]

Edit: according to Star Trek Star Charts, the Bajoran sun is a G2V class star with an absolute magnitude of 4.7, very similar to our own sun (G2V 4.83). So assuming Bajor XI is about the same distance from its sun as Earth is from ours (93 million miles), and assuming the distances shown in the map are to scale (which is almost certainly not the case), then the distance between Bajor XI and Deep Space Nine's location is approximately 35 million miles, much shorter than I expected, and about 2/3 of the distance to Mars's closest approach to the Earth.

Also, [Deep Space Nine rotates constantly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144088/12857), but AFAIK its a continuous, unpowered rotation that doesn't count as a "maneuver" in my opinion.

Technically Deep Space Nine was built by the Cardassians, owned by the Bajorans, and administrated by the Federation, so I'm not 100% certain whether it qualifies as a "Federation space station", but presumably it would become one once Bajor eventually joined the Federation (which never officially happened in canon to my knowledge but was always the writers' eventual intent).

Comment: Wow! Beautiful answer. I haven't seen the pilot since it originally aired - I had a vague recollection of some station doing something, but I didn't realize it was so central to a plot. I'm curious if it's ever occurred in a plot besides this major move, I'm not sure if I need to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @Are you looking for any episode in particular? Or just curious about the abilities of federation starbases?

Comment: This one I *should have* known about. If I did, I would have asked something like (besides the major move central to the plot of DS9, has... ever...) I think you are right - it's more about abilities. This is definitely an answer to my question as asked, I'll think about asking something new separately. Thanks!

Comment: Was DS9 ever officially a _Federation_ station? Wasn't it technically a Bajoran station under Federation administration?

Comment: As I remeber it was a cardassian station. Left by the cardassians and taken over by bajorans and federation. So if we take the QA literally, it hardly counts because it's hardly a "Federation space station".

Comment: While various commenters are correct that DS9 was **never** strictly a Federation station on-screen (it became one in both the continuing novel series and _Star Trek: Online_), it's pretty much the only example of what the OP is asking for. No other space station, from the beginning of the Classic series through _Star Trek Beyond_, is seen to do more than orbit and maybe rotate.

Comment: Depending on what the wormhole is actually orbiting, this maneuver could have been really easy or really difficult. Traversing a distance is "easy" - just accelerate a bit and then decelerate a bit. Moving to different orbits is "hard" and takes a lot more energy or some help from large gravity wells.

Comment: @Ellesedil Good analysis from a real-world standpoint, but a major aspect of the maneuver in Emissary is using the station's deflector field to "lower [its] inertial mass", so the various conversations that physics is usually so obsessed are clearly behaving pretty loosely here.